# Reversing the order of integration in $\int_{-1}^{3}\int_{x^2}^{2x+3} x \, dy \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^{3}\int_{x^2}^{2x+3} x \, dy \, dx$$

I am trying to reverse the order of integration for this problem. I drew the region bounded by the functions of $x$ but I've hit a block.

Comment: In case it helps: in this order, the two integrals are asking "what are all the $x$-values in the universe that are in the region of integration?" and "for any given $x$-value, what are the possible $y$-values such that $(x,y)$ is in the region?" Switching the order of integration means asking the questions "what are all the $y$-values in the universe that are in the region of integration?" and "for any given $y$-value, what are the possible $x$-values such that $(x,y)$ is in the region?". Can you answer the first question? the second question?

Comment: Have you tried dividing the region into pieces that you can write integrals for?

Comment: To answer @David K after drawing out the region in the xy-plane, I noticed I could split into a region below y=1 and region above y=1.

Comment: To answer Greg Martin, I realized from sketching the region that the y value has range 0 $ 0 \leq y \leq 9 $

Answer (score 1):

If you drew the region, you see that the low $y$-value is $0$ and the high $y$-value is $9$. So the outer integral will be $\int_{y=0}^{y=9}$.

As your eyes move up from $0$ to $9$, for a time the left edge and right edge are both parts of a parabola. Then at $y=1$ the left edge transitions to a line. So the outer integral needs to be broken up: $\int_{y=0}^{y=1}+\int_{y=1}^{y=9}$.

For the lower section, the left curve is $x=-\sqrt{y}$ and the right curve is $x=\sqrt{y}$.

Then at $y=1$ the left curve transitions to $x=\frac{y-3}{2}$.

So you have
$$\int_{y=0}^{y=1}\int_{x=-\sqrt{y}}^{x=\sqrt{y}}+\int_{y=1}^{y=9}\int_{x=\frac{y-3}{2}}^{x=\sqrt{y}}$$

Comment: Ok I follow everything you've written so far. Moving forward doesn't the first term in your last line reduce to 0?

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out. Your answer helped a great deal.