# Reversing the order of integration for this double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{2x}^{4x-x^2}1\,dy\,dx $

For this problem, I've graphed the region and determined the bounds for $y$ as $ 0 \leq y \leq 4$. I'm trying to determine the functions of $y$ that bound the $x$ values. Well, I know the upper bound is $x = y/2$.

Comment: MAybe something is missing. I only see a single integral.

Comment: Thanks for telling me.

Comment: Can you solve $4x-x^2=y$ as an equation over $x$?

Comment: This looks somewhat similar to [Reversing the order of integration in $\int_{-1}^{3}\int_{x^2}^{2x+3} x \, dy \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3898464/139123), except that this one is simpler in one way because the endpoints of the parabolic arc actually are a minimum and maximum. It is just a little more complicated in another way because $4x-x^2$ is not symmetric around the $y$ axis.

Comment: @TitoEliatron I'd love to but how would I go about doing that?

Comment: How do you solve $4x-x^2=3$ or $4x-x^2=5$ or... $4x-x^2=c$ for some $c\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: @TitoEliatron...sigh right I hear you. Move the c to the left side and use the quadratic formula...I'm an idiot

Answer (score 0):

When $x$ goes from $0$ to $2$, both $2x$ and $4x-x^2$ goes from $0$ to $4$, and $4x-x^2\geqslant2x$. So, when $y$ goes from $0$ to $4$, $x$ goes from $2-\sqrt{4-y}$ to $\frac y2$. Therefore, the answer is$$\int_0^4\int_{2-\sqrt{4-y}}^{y/2}1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.$$